# select last element in DOM javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i'm new to this dom im going to get the tha last child of this xml document but unable to get this can anybody explain why my code seems correct to me but but dont know why it is not getting the messages lastchild's, so what are the other possible ways to do this , i just want to get the `talk 123` from this msg

the xml file

```
<msg category="short">
    <person1>
        <time>
             r
            <message>Djssjs</message>
        </time>
    </person1>
    <person2>
        <time>
            r
            <message>1234fdg</message>
        </time>
    </person2>
    <person1>
        <time>
            r
            <message> talk 123</message>
        </time>
    </person1>
</msg>
```

javascript

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("msg")[0].lastChild;
    var m = x.childNodes[2];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = m.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: If you indent your XML, you'll have an easier time seeing that `x` is the second `<person1>` tag, which only has a single child `<time>` - therefore `m` is undefined.

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol said, there's only 1 child node of `<person1>` (and `<person2>` fwiw).  "talk 123" is the child of the child of `<person1>` ie `\\person1\time\message`

Comment: yea guys that is child of time has two chhild may be first text seconnd msg but i can not get its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the type of `xml` here... I assumed an object containing a string.

If I'm correct, it needs to be parsed using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Then, we get (in order):

1. the `<msg>` tag,
2. the
   [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild),
   which is `<person1>` here,
3. and finally the `<message>` tag's innerHTML.

```js
var xml = {
  responseXML: '<msg category="short"> <person1> <time> r <message>Djssjs</message> </time> </person1> <person2> <time> r <message>1234fdg</message> </time> </person2> <person1> <time>  r <message> talk 123</message> </time> </person1> </msg>'
};


function myFunction(xml) {
  
  // Get the response from the object.
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  //console.log(xmlDoc);

  // Parse the string to HTML
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlParsed = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc, "application/xml");
  //console.log(xmlParsed);

  // Get the <msg> tage
  var msgTag = xmlParsed.getElementsByTagName("msg")[0];
  //console.log(msgTag.tagName);

  // Get the last child, <person1>
  var personLast = msgTag.lastElementChild;
  //console.log(personLast);

  // Get the <msg> innerHTML
  var msgLast = personLast.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].innerHTML;
  //console.log(msgLast);

  // Display in document
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msgLast;
}

myFunction(xml);
```

```css
#demo{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Function result should be here.</div>
```

The console logs aren't commented in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/pZLLwP?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, there may be multiple issues here. Not entirely sure about XML documents but javascript will consider the nextline character as the last child. So the last child would be text. You can test that by logging x on the console.This should fix the current function according to the xml here.

```
function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("msg")[0].childNodes[childNodes.length-2];
var m = x.childNodes[1].childnodes[1];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = m.innerHTML;
```

}